# Please help me find the actual error in this jungle of compiler errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I can't for the life of me figure out what the compiler wants from me.

Can anyone experienced with compiler messages help me decipher what it wants, please?
I can't even provide code bits because I've no idea whats going on.

I'm using g++-4.7 with -std=c++11

http://pastebin.com/AxYMd6L8

It seems it complains about SimpleMapSquare and something about it being an allocator?
It's nothing like that. SimpleMapSquare is defined as:

```
#pragma once

namespace BlackDragonEngine
{
struct SimpleMapSquare
{
  int TileID;
};
}
```

I wrote about 400+ lines of templated code yesterday and just tried to include the header for it in my main app and boom this happens...

I don't even know where to start...please help.

EDIT:
A search for "vector<" in my project returns this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkOSu.png
I expanded the revelant files (the ones I created yesterday)

The reason I wrote so much code without testing is because I'm converting my engine from C# to C++, so the logical side is already right and I can't test incomplete code.

EDIT 2:
Here are all usages of "SimpleMapSquare" https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKC8G.png

EDIT3:
Thanks to Konrad I was able to pinpoint the exact line and find the error... ignore the searches above as I forgot to include *.inl files (where the template code implementation is located)

Comment: Try separating out your code into some smaller units and tackle them one at a time. IF you write 400 lines of code in one sitting it's going to be a nightmare to debug as you've discovered. Without seeing all the source it's going to be very difficult to provide an answer to all of that lot...

Comment: First lesson: Don't write 400 untested/uncompiled code. Write and test little by little.

Comment: Next time, **do** provide the relevant code, please! The error message clearly shows the context of the error (everything which mentions “required here” is a dead giveaway).

Comment: "I don't even know where to start. " Start with first error, and fix them one by one. That's traditional way to do it.

Comment: @SigTerm but there's no line that contains the actual error. Just rabble dabble in compiler internal files...

Comment: @xNidhogg: "but there's no line..." Lies. How about this one: `error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct BlackDragonEngine::SimpleMapSquare’`? Learn to read compiler error messages.

Comment: @SigTerm sorry I meant line as in "line in the file where the error happens" I just see compiler specific files and lines. I do see the errors. It's resolved now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the following class somewhere:

```
class std::vector<sf::Vector2<int>, BlackDragonEngine::SimpleMapSquare>
```

The second type argument of `std::vector` is the allocator type!

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I did a search and nowhere did I find a use like this. Here are search results: http://i.imgur.com/g8L1l.png I expanded the revelant classes I created yesterday.

Comment: @xNidhogg Note that there might be spaces everywhere, as in `vector <` try searching for uses of `SimpleMapSquare` instead. But even that isn’t foolproof since it might be used in templates. **But this is all unnecessary** since the error message gives you a line number! … TileMap.inl:42

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thats what I needed. The line...thank you. I still can't find it in the pastebin itself but I managed to fix the error. Stupid me didn't search the *.inl files... thank you

Comment: @xNidhogg Unfortunately, none. It simply takes practice and a lot of determination and patience. I’ve had to deal with compiler messages that are > 5 MB in size … fun! One tip perhaps: you can make the message clearer by replacing deeply nested templates, e.g. `std::basic_string<char, …>` by `string` and generally removing all `std::` qualifiers (but this might also obscure the real error sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SimpleMapSquare shold contain definition of types `value_type`, `pointer` and `reference`.

It is like the STL is treating SimpleMapSquare as an iterator, allocator or other traits requiring classes.

Did you pass it as a wrong parameter somewhere ?